# Understanding css line-height property

Tags: css

I was playing around with the line-height property from the following site:

http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_float6

```
div.container
{
    width:100%;
    margin:0px;
    border:1px solid gray;
    line-height:150%;
}
```

I tried to understand about line-height and I read this:

> On block level elements, the line-height CSS property specifies the
>   minimal height of line boxes within the element.

From:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/line-height#Examples

But interestingly in the example above from w3schools, changing the line-height property will increase the size of the containing div element which seems to be contradicting with the statement made in mozilla site. Hence I would appreciate greatly if any can offer clarification what actually a line-height does.

Thanks

Comment: How does that behaviour contradict that statement? If you increase the line height it will increase the size of the div. The div contains the line so it needs to increase to contain it.

Comment: I'm not understanding what you're confused about.

Comment: I feel duty bound to add that content from W3Schools can be problematic. More on that [here](http://w3fools.com/). I find MDN to be much more helpful, or anything on [CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

line-height is actually given when we want to align the block elements in between along y-axis.

Forexample, i have a singled line text in

w3schools

and para height is 20px. The paragraph will be written in its own default way but if i use line-height equals the height of the paragraph then text in

say W3schools will be aligned in the middle along y-axis. While if you want to horizontally align (x-axis align) your text then text-align:center is used for this purpose.

Remember, line-height do not totally depend on the height of its own element height. But it changes as follows.

1. If you have a single line text,

   height is 20px then give line-height: 20px to vertically align the text or vertically middle of text.
2. If you have a two line of text,

   height is 20px then give the line-height:10px and with the small padding-top to vertically align the text.

I hope this will lift you up. And i think you will not need to browse google more. If more you want explanation then i will give you jfiddle code. :)

Answer (score 0):

It's not contradictory. Setting the line-height property on a `div` will apply the same line-height property to all inline children. So in your example, by setting the line-height property on the div, any child elements that are `display: inline` will have the new line-height applied to them. When the height of those child elements is increased, the height of the parent `div` increases to be able to contain the child elements.